# how to iterate through last column of the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a table dynamically created using knockout js as below:

My problem is to dynamically assign an id for the newly created columns.  I need to iterate over the last column.

```
<table>
    <tr data-bind="foreach: activeColumns">
        <th data-bind="text: display"></th>
    </tr>
    <tbody id="sortable" data-bind="foreach: rows">
        <tr data-bind="foreach: $root.activeColumns">
            <td id="uniquename">
                <span  data-bind="visible: readonly, text: $parent[property]"></span>
                <input data-bind="visible: !readonly, value: $parent[property]"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to iterate through `tr` elements for selecting the last one, you can use `:last` selector or `last` method:

```
$('#sortable tr').last(); // last tr element  
$('#sortable td').last(); // last td element
```

In case that you want to change attributes of last `tr`'s `td` elements, you can use `each` method:

```
$('#sortable tr').last().children().each(function(index){
   // $(this).attr('id', 'wildguess' + index)
})
```

Or `attr` method:

```
$('#sortable tr').last().children().attr('id', function(index){
   return 'wildguess' + ++index // unique IDs bases on the index
})
```

> My problem is to dynamically assign an id for the newly created columns.

However best solution is generating  unique  IDs at first.

Comment: thank you very much,I want to change id of all tr's last td elements can you suggest something